# Capistrano: RSolr::Error::Http - 404 Not Found when reindexing Solr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, capistrano, sunspot

I have not found any concrete examples that could possibly help address my problem. I previously had the sunspot gem working with Capistrano before my update to Rails 4 and Ruby 2. Any help sorting this error out would be greatly appreciated.

**Gemfile:**

```
gem 'sunspot_rails', :github => 'hsbt/sunspot', :branch => 'enabled-rails4'
gem 'sunspot_solr', :github => 'hsbt/sunspot', :branch => 'enabled-rails4'
```

**.gitignore**

```
solr/pids
solr/default
```

**config/deploy.rb**

```
namespace :deploy do
  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
  end

  desc "Migrate Database"
  task :migrate_db do
    run "cd #{current_path} && rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production"
    run "touch #{current_path}/tmp/restart.txt"
  end

  desc "Create Solr Directory"
  task :setup_solr_data_dir do
    run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/solr/data"
  end
end

namespace :solr do
  desc "start solr"
  task :start, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "cd #{current_path} && RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} bundle exec sunspot-solr start --port=8983 --data-directory=#{shared_path}/solr/data --pid-dir=#{shared_path}/pids > /dev/null 2>&1 || true"
  end
  desc "stop solr"
  task :stop, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run ("cd #{current_path} && RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} bundle exec sunspot-solr stop --port=8983 --data-directory=#{shared_path}/solr/data --pid-dir=#{shared_path}/pids > /dev/null 2>&1 || true")
  end
  desc "reindex the whole database"
  task :reindex, :roles => :app do
    stop
    run "rm -rf #{shared_path}/solr/data"
    start
    run "cd #{current_path} && yes | RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:reindex"
  end
end

after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup", "deploy:migrate_db",'deploy:setup_solr_data_dir', 'solr:start', 'solr:reindex'
```

**Error Message:**

```
  * 2013-06-24 12:19:20 executing `solr:start'
  * executing "cd /home/username/apps/MyApplication/current && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec sunspot-solr start --port=8983 --data-directory=/home/username/apps/MyApplication/shared/solr/data --pid-dir=/home/username/apps/MyApplication/shared/pids > /dev/null 2>&1 || true"
    servers: ["0.0.0.0"]
    [0.0.0.0] executing command
    command finished in 1349ms
  * executing "cd /home/username/apps/MyApplication/current && yes | RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:reindex"
    servers: ["0.0.0.0"]
    [0.0.0.0] executing command
 ** [out :: 0.0.0.0] *Note: the reindex task will remove your current indexes and start from scratch.
 ** [out :: 0.0.0.0] 
 ** [out :: 0.0.0.0] If you have a large dataset, reindexing can take a very long time, possibly weeks.
 ** [out :: 0.0.0.0] 
 ** [out :: 0.0.0.0] This is not encouraged if you have anywhere near or over 1 million rows.
 ** [out :: 0.0.0.0] 
 ** [out :: 0.0.0.0] Are you sure you want to drop your indexes and completely reindex? (y/n)
 ** [out :: 0.0.0.0] 
 ** [out :: 0.0.0.0] D, [2013-06-24T12:18:59.139035 #2262] DEBUG -- :   SOLR Request (12.2ms)  [ path=#<RSolr::Client:0x00000007003988> parameters={data: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><delete><query>type:Project</query></delete>, headers: {"Content-Type"=>"text/xml"}, method: post, params: {:wt=>:ruby}, query: wt=ruby, path: update, uri: http://localhost:8983/solr/default/update?wt=ruby, open_timeout: , read_timeout: , retry_503: , retry_after_limit: } ]
 ** [out :: 0.0.0.0] 
 ** [out :: 0.0.0.0] rake aborted!
 ** [out :: 0.0.0.0] 
 ** [out :: 0.0.0.0] RSolr::Error::Http - 404 Not Found
 ** [out :: 0.0.0.0] 
 ** [out :: 0.0.0.0] Error:     NOT_FOUND
 ** [out :: 0.0.0.0] 
 ** [out :: 0.0.0.0] 
 ** [out :: 0.0.0.0] Request Data:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your Solr server does not respond to the endpoint you expect. Your URL seems to be:
**localhost:8983/solr/default** (with the handler being /update under that).

Is there Solr endpoint there? Can you access it manually?

If not, I would recommend changing your start commands to log to a file instead of **/dev/null** and seeing what exceptions you get.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Alexandre! This has caused me much frustration. If I understand you correctly, my sunspot.yml should be pointing to the IP of my server, for the production environment instead of localhost?

Comment: That depends on your setup, but the error is because it cannot find Solr server. If you don't have one on localhost, then it should point to the one you have.

Comment: Alexandre, when I go to localhost:8983/solr on the server I am getting 500 error 'Could not initialize class org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher' ... I have a feeling Capistrano is not installing Sunspot properly on the server.

Comment: Ok, so it looks like you do have a server on local host. Is that expected? If so, you need to get it to work (a separate problem/issue). If not and your real server is somewhere else, you need to point to that (as described above).

Comment: @AlexandreRafalovitch how could I log to a file?

Comment: The easiest thing is just to redirect output to the file when you start the server (on Unix with a command like 'tee', or on Unix and Windows with > 2>). More comprehensive approach would be to setup Solr logger properly, but that's a different question.